# How to use pow() in Swift 3 and get an Int

Tags: swift3, pow

I have the following code:

```
let lootBase = Int(pow((Decimal(level + 1)), 3) * 2)
let lootMod = Int(pow(Decimal(level), 2) * 2)
value = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lootBase)) + lootMod)
```

I need value to be an Int.  The error I get when I try to surround the pow calculation for Int() is:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type int with an argument list of type Decimal

How do I use the pow function with Int in Swift 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Int` does not have an initializer taking `Decimal`, so you cannot convert `Decimal` to `Int` directly with an initializer syntax like `Int(...)`.

You can use `pow(Decimal, Int)` like this:

```
let lootBase = Int(pow((Decimal(level + 1)), 3) * 2 as NSDecimalNumber)
let lootMod = Int(pow(Decimal(level), 2) * 2 as NSDecimalNumber)

let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lootBase))) + lootMod
```

Or else, you can use `pow(Double, Double)` like this:

```
let lootBase = Int(pow((Double(level + 1)), 3) * 2)
let lootMod = Int(pow(Double(level), 2) * 2)

let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lootBase))) + lootMod
```

But, if you only calculate an integer value's power to 2 or 3, both `pow(Decimal, Int)` and `pow(Double, Double)` are far from efficient.

You can declared a simple functions like `squared` or `cubed` like this:

```
func squared(_ val: Int) -> Int {return val * val}
func cubed(_ val: Int) -> Int {return val * val * val}
```

and use them instead of `pow(..., 2)` or `pow(..., 3)`:

```
let lootBase = cubed(level + 1) * 2
let lootMod = squared(level) * 2

let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lootBase))) + lootMod
```

(Assuming `level` is an `Int`.)

Answer (score 2):

Int init() method with no parameter is deprecated for Decimal conversion and should be replaced with Int.init(truncating number: NSNumber) like this

```
let lootMod = Int(truncating: pow(Decimal(level), 2) * 2 as NSDecimalNumber)
```

Or

```
let lootMod = Int(truncating: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: pow(Decimal(level), 2) * 2))
```

Comment: Hi mulot, welcome! Is your question what the best practice for casting a ```Decimal``` to an ```Int``` is?

Comment: Hi Thomas Murphy. Thank you. I was just adding a comment on this topic based on what I experienced. But if you think that there is a best practice between the two functions I've mentioned, I take it!

Answer (score 1):

Use decimal for both parameters of pow function. 
Maybe the second argument of pow that you are providing is treated as Int instead of Decimal. 
Try something like this:

```
let lootMod = Int(pow(Decimal(level), Decimal(2)) * 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late for an answer, however:

If level is an Int you could cast it to Float and Use powf() instead of pow() :

```
let lootBase = Int(powf(Float(level) + 1, 3)) * 2
let lootMod = Int(powf(Float(level), 2)) * 2
```

If you use UInt32 for addition you should cast all variables to UInt32 before you cast the result to Int:

```
let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lootBase)) + UInt32(lootMod))
```

PS: I´m not an expert so check yourself if that works as you expect